# Linq GroupBy on multiple columns with potentials null value

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to make this work :

```
 var customerSearchResult = customers.GroupBy(                               
            x => new {
                x.CustomerID,
                x.email,
                x.CreatedOn,
                x.FirstName,
                x.LastName,
                x.Profile == null ? -1 : x.Profile.Value
            })
            .Select(csr => new CustomerSearchResult
            {
                CustomerID = csr.Key.CustomerID,
                Email = csr.Key.email,
                CreatedOn = csr.Key.CreatedOn

            });
```

I am getting an

> Error CS0746  Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type
>   members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or
>   member access.

Because of this line `x.Profile == null ? -1 : x.Profile.Value`
Profile can be null.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare name for this variable in `Anonymous` class:

```
var customerSearchResult = customers.GroupBy(                               
            x => new {
                x.CustomerID,
                x.email,
                x.CreatedOn,
                x.FirstName,
                x.LastName,
                Profile = x.Profile == null ? -1 : x.Profile.Value
            })
            .Select(csr => new CustomerSearchResult
            {
                CustomerID = csr.Key.CustomerID,
                Email = csr.Key.email,
                CreatedOn = csr.Key.CreatedOn
            });
```

As @Abion47 mentioned in comment, you could simplify your assihnment as:

```
Profile = x.Profile?.Value ?? -1
```

Comment: As an alternative, if you are using C# 6, I'd suggest using the null-conditional operator `?` and the null-coalescing operator `??` to make the code look cleaner. i.e. `Profile = x.Profile?.Value ?? -1;`